# Is collections.max deprecated or renamed in the latest Memgraph platform?

Tags: memgraphdb

I recently noticed that the latest Memgraph Platform update removed several stored procedures in the `collection` module, among others. Now, I only see two procedures remaining in the `collection` module: `collections.partition` and `collections.split`.

I have been using `collections.max`, but it seems it is no longer available. Has it been deprecated or perhaps renamed? Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The procedure you mentioned hasn't been completely removed. It has been [transformed into function](https://memgraph.com/docs/advanced-algorithms/available-algorithms/collections#max). The way you use them has changed a bit. For collections.max, you no longer need the CALL keyword. Now you can use it directly:

```
RETURN collections.max([-1, -2, -3.3]) AS max;
```